# Interactive transition with ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, transition

After some research im still a little confused regarding to interactive transitions in swift. I like to make a transition between two ViewControllers using a pan gesture. So far so good.

Unfortunately the most sources on the web are outdated or a little weird, which makes it pretty hard for me to decide whats the best practice.

What i like to achieve is this:
[simple wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6bOw.png)

I got a VC that contains a label and the gesture recognizer. By panning up from the bottom it should animate to the next VC, containing a stack of images, based on my touch position. The transition should work backwards as well.

I also found out that it might be the best way to use `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning` controlled by `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`.

Maybe you can tell me a better way to realize this or have an example for me to check out.

Comment: There's a WWDC video on the topic, perhaps that's more helpful than the sources you were looking at :) https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/

Comment: Thanks for your response. The video is pretty good explained but unfortunately its from the year 2013. It would be nice to know if this practise is still the state of art

Comment: You can find a good resource here: http://mathewsanders.com/interactive-transitions-in-swift